# Odoo 8 error: werkzeug: Error on request:

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, werkzeug, odoo-8

When I start odoo server, it starts correctly, showing the OK mesage:

```
root@des [/opt/odoo/addons/web]# /etc/init.d/odoo start
Starting Odoo Server Daemon (odoo-server):                 [  OK  ]
root@des [/opt/odoo/addons/web]#
```

When I see log file, I see this:

```
root@des [/opt/odoo/addons/web]# tail -50 /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
2015-04-04 19:46:33,637 21486 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0
2015-04-04 19:46:33,637 21486 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/opt/odoo/addons', '/opt/odoo/openerp/addons']
2015-04-04 19:46:33,637 21486 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2015-04-04 19:46:33,637 21486 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2015-04-04 19:46:33,637 21486 INFO ? openerp: database user: odoo
2015-04-04 19:46:33,931 21486 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
root@des [/opt/odoo/addons/web]#
```

The first time I connect to the site, I get an internal server error web page, and this error in the log:

```
2015-04-04 20:08:31,283 25128 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2015-04-04 20:08:31,961 25128 INFO ? openerp.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2015-04-04 20:08:31,981 25128 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 180, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 168, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 281, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1279, in __call__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1298, in load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 80, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/report/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import models
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/report/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import report
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/report/models/report.py", line 71, in <module>
    version = re.search('([0-9.]+)', out).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

How can I solve that error?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: That seems like a bug in odoo, I'd file it against their issue tracker.